# Can't delete Azure Policy assignment using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-policy

I create an Azure policy and assigned it to a subscription, and now want to delete it using the Azure CLI on my Ubuntu terminal. The command doesn't output any success response and the policy isn't deleted.

This is the command I am using:

```
az policy assignment delete --name "Enforce tag on resource"
```

Both of these command return nothing:

```
az policy assignment list | grep -i "Enforce tag on resource"
az policy definition list | grep -i "Enforce tag on resource"
```

but I see the assignment in the Azure console:

[image]

Does it mean my assignment is deleted but remains in the console for later deletion? Note, I am able to delete it using the Azure console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the correct scope together with correct name (is different from **displayname**)

Here is how I was able to delete the policy assignment:

- Go to Policy

[image]

- Copy whole **Assignment Id** link (there is a icon/button to copy it)

For example:

```
/subscriptions/<subsc_id>/resourcegroups/bky-test-aks-rg-n/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/bky-test-aks-n/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/test-assignment
```

- Now use delete command as follows:

  ```
    az policy assignment delete --name 'test-assignment' --scope '/subscriptions/<subsc_id>/resourcegroups/bky-test-aks-rg-n/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/bky-test-aks-n'
  ```

Needless to say, you must have already logged in to Azure (az login) and the user should have enough privileges to perform the action.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the spaces in the name. Try this:

```
policyname="Enforce tag on resource"
az policy assignment delete --name "$policyname"
```

Comment: I suspected that but thought the ' " ' should take care of that. I will recreate this tomorrow.